# Automatically regenerate managed identity credentials

Tags: azure-functions, azure-logic-apps, azure-webjobs, azure-managed-identity

I have recently started working on a project where we are dealing with Managed Identities. There is one API which will create a managed identity on a storage account and one other Api which is for accessing that storage account. Now what I want is that whenever a user accesses any storage account (using GET) he would get the valid credentials and for that I have to regenerate the credentials if they are not in the valid state. So, any suggestions on how I can achieve this functionality? My thoughts are for some kind of Web job with polling or logical app, functions etc which will monitor the managed identity and will update if required. How can achieve this functionality ? To regenerate basically I want to update the identity metadata and for that we already have an API ( Something like GetIdentityMetadata ).

Comment: Are you talking about Access token ? Could include how are u generating the token Managed Idntity Credentials?

Comment: @RithwikBojja we have an API something like GetIdentityMetadata which I wanted to call for regeneration of metadata associated with the identity.